# $twig->render() exception - argument must be array, string given

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying return rendered template if some condition is true in this function:

```
* @Route("/results", name="front.tour.results")
* @Template
*/
public function indexAction(Request $request, $countryUrl=NULL, $placeUrl=NULL)
{
  ...

  if(condition) {

  $twig = $this->get('twig');

  return $twig->render('@App/FrontModule/Tour/hotelList.html.twig', [
            'allPossiblePlaces' => $allPossiblePlaces
        ]);
  }
```

But i am getting exception with message:

> Argument 2 passed to
>   Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine::renderResponse() must be of the
>   type array, string given

I am 100% sure that variable `$allPossiblePlaces` is array so i don't understant. Any ideas?

Comment: You use Symfony? Try using `$this->render`. You have exception in renderResponse method, so I think problem is in twig service... bad use or something else

Comment: Why you didn't use `$this->render`?

Comment: Thanx it work. Yes i am using symfony. But still i don't understand i have another function (only without route annotation) it works like i write in my question. What is the difference? (With array parameters too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
* @Route("/results", name="front.tour.results")
* @Template
*/
public function indexAction(Request $request, $countryUrl=NULL, $placeUrl=NULL)
{
  ...

  if(condition) {

  return $this->render('@App/FrontModule/Tour/hotelList.html.twig', [
        'allPossiblePlaces' => $allPossiblePlaces
    ]);
}
```

If you want more capabilities around view engine in Symfony, read this documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/templating.html

Answer (score -11):

Change your line to

```
return $twig->render('@App/FrontModule/Tour/hotelList.html.twig', array(
            'allPossiblePlaces' => $allPossiblePlaces
        ));
```

And it will work.

Basically, its a syntax issue. Twig parses each argument it recieves, and it cannot parse '[]' notation to an array and hence the issue.

Comment: This is not true, I use `[]` everywhere in my code and when rendering twig and I never had an issue with it.